# BackgroundWorker and server in c#

Tags: c#, client-server, backgroundworker

I'm trying to copy files between server and client in c# when a button is clicked.
I wish to use a background worker because I don't want the copy to make my form stuck while copying.
I have this code:

```
    private void connectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (!isConnected)
         {
             clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
             connectBtn.Text = "Disconnect From Server";
             connectBtn.Refresh();
             clientSock.Connect(remoteIpAddress, remotePort);
             statusColor.BackColor = Color.Green;
             statusColor.Refresh();
             isConnected = true;
             buttonAddDirectory.Enabled = true;
             buttonAddFile.Enabled = true;
             var bg = new BackgroundWorker();
             bg.DoWork += (sender, e) => copyDllsToServer();

             bg.RunWorkerAsync();
             if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy != true)
                 backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
         }
     }
```

The copying function is: copyDllsToServer().

When doing that, I get the following error: `A local variable named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'sender', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else`.
How can I resolve it?

Will this `BackgroundWorker` work properly when multiple clients run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
bg.DoWork += (sender1, e) => copyDllsToServer(sender1, e);
                    ^_____________
```

instead of

```
bg.DoWork += (sender, e) => copyDllsToServer();
```

or use method group as

```
bg.DoWork += copyDllsToServer;
```

Why not used asynchronous methods of `Socket` class?

The `Socket` class realizes [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM) pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938.aspx). Examine [Socket Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket_methods%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which starts with `Begin/End`.

Comment: Worked. Thanks. Regarding your question, I don't know, I wasn't sure how to do it, so I asked, and got the recommendation to use the bg...